# Null space of $A$ is orthogonal to column space of $A^*$ but orthogonal to $A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a complex matrix 
$$A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & i  & 0 \\
    i & 0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$$
I want to show that the null space is orthogonal to $\rm Col(A^*)$ but not orthogonal to $\rm Col(A^T).$

My attempt: Null space of $A$ is an one dim vector space  with basis $(0,0,1)^T$ and $\rm Col(A^*)$ has basis $\{(1, -i, 0)^T, (1, 0, 0)^T\}$. Then  trivially the inner  product of basis of column space and null space is zero. So they are orthogonal. But but how can I show that $N(A)$ is not orthogonal to $C(A^T)?$

Comment: Your null space isn't right. But to answer your question: just find $A^t$, then find the column space, then show the null space is not orthogonal to a vector in the column space.

Answer (score 0):

> Null space is a one dim vector space with basis $(0,0,1)^T$

So are you saying that $Ax = 0$ for $x=(0,0,1)^T$?

You also incorrectly calculated $Col(A^*)$, since, for example, the vector $(-i, 0, 1)^T$ is an element of $Col(A^*)$, but both your basis elements have $0$ on the third place so any combination would also have the form $(*, *, 0)$.

To show that $N(A)$ is not orthogonal to $C(A^T)$, it's enough to find *one* element of $N(A)$ and *one* element of $C(A^T)$ such that the two elements are not orthogonal.

Comment: Sorry. $N(A)$ is generated by $(-i,1,-1)^T.$